# AS3 ViewStack content clipping

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, viewstack

I have the next code (Flash Builder 4.5)

This main appliction file, for testing me viewstack component.

TabPanelTest

```
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                tp.AddPanel("111", new Button());
                tp.AddPanel("444", new TestPanel());
                tp.AddPanel("2222222", new Button());
                tp.AddPanel("3333333333", new Button());

            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tp.RemoveAllPanels();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <ns1:TabPanel id="tp" x="25" y="27" width="321" height="199">
    </ns1:TabPanel>
    <s:Button x="439" y="25" label="Кнопка1" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:Application>
```

This is TabPanel, that have public methods AddPanel and RemoveAllPanels.

TabPanel

```
            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //buttons1.dataProvider=new ArrayCollection();
            }

            public function AddPanel(name:String, element:IVisualElement):void{
                var panel:NavigatorContent=new NavigatorContent();
                panel.label=name;
                panel.addElement(element);
                panels.addElement(panel);
            }
            public function RemoveAllPanels():void{
                //panels.swapElements(swapElementsAt(0,2);
                panels.removeAllElements();
                /*var but:Button;
                but=new Button();
                but.label=name;
                buttons.addElement(but);    */          
            }           
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:ViewStack id="panels" x="0" y="31" width="100%" height="100%" borderColor="#000000"
                  borderStyle="solid" borderVisible="true" clipContent="true" includeInLayout="true">
    </mx:ViewStack> 
    <s:ButtonBar id="buttons1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" dataProvider="{panels}"
                 justificationStyle="pushOutOnly"/>
</s:Group>
```

This is testing panel, that have size more than viewstack, and it must clipping.
TestPanel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.NavigatorContent;           
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                NavigatorContent(this.parent.parent.parent).label="bebe";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="163" y="35" width="315" height="209" label="Кнопка"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:Group>
```

When i click to "444" in buuton bar my content don't clipping. What's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line with TestPanel custom component: -

```
<s:Button x="163" y="35" width="315" height="209" label="Кнопка"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

If you are adding any component to parent container: -

child component will consider x and y position with respect to parent.
If you want to fit your child component you should use x=0 and y=0
as well as width = 100% and height = 100%

Try this and see out put: -

```
<s:Button x="163" y="35" width="100%" height="100%" label="Кнопка"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Again Try this and see out put: -

```
<s:Button x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" label="Кнопка"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

You will come to know how component behavior.

Hope this may solve your problem.....